# Induced current in open circuit and closed circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

In a closed circuit, electric current is induced so as to oppose the changing magnetic flux as per conservation of energy. However, in open circuit, emf is induced across its ends. How it is related to flux change?

Comment: EMF is not defined in an open circuit. You always have to specify a path. If the circuit is open and you are interested in the fields, then you have to go beyond the induction term and calculate the entire solution of Maxwell's equations with the appropriate boundary conditions of the problem, which is usually much, much harder than an EMF problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a complete conducting circuit then an induced emf will produce an induced current in the circuit.
The direction of the induced current will be such as to oppose the change/motion producing it which is Lenz's law.
If there is no induced current then there will be no opposition to the motion.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my book it says that " An EMF is induced in a circuit to oppose the flux change, while closed circuit is special case in which since the circuit is complete, a current flows"